# Order of flow in my simple calculator in Python

Tags: python

Please help... it might be something quick and easy I hope. I'm 9 days in to Python. I have code for a simple calculator. I cant figure out  how to stop the calculator from seeking the values to be calculated if the selection of operations from the choices 1-4 is invalid to start with. If someone selects > 4 (from options 1,2,3,4) it returns 'Invalid input' but then proceeds to ask for value to calculate. How can I stop this from happening? It should cease after 'Invalid input' and be run again.

Here is the code:

```
#Simple calculator
# define my simple functions

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def min(x, y):
    return x - y

def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

def div(x, y):
    return x / y

# provide options for operations
print("Please select an operation.")
print("For addition select 1. ")
print("For subtraction select 2.")
print("For multiplication  select 3.")
print("For division select 4.")

option = input("Please enter the number of your option 1, 2, 3, 4:")

# limit option to 1,2,3,4
if option > '4':
    print("Invalid input. Please select 1,2,3 or 4.")

elif option < '5':

    print("Please select an operation.")
    print("For addition select 1. ")
    print("For subtraction select 2.")
    print("For multiplication  select 3.")
    print("For division select 4.")


num1 = float(input( "Please enter the first value: "))
num2 = float(input( "Please enter the second value: "))



if choice == '1':
    print(num1, " + ", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))

elif choice == '2':
    print(num1, " - ", num2, "=", min(num1, num2))

elif choice == '3':
    print(num1, " * ", num2, "=", mul(num1,num2))

elif choice =='4':
    print(num1, " / ", num2, "=", div(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Um... instead of `print("Invalid input. Please select 1,2,3 or 4.")` just print `print("Invalid input.")`? It's just printing the request for the next number, but it is ending after that. It's not actually accepting a new input.

Comment: why do you think it should exit? You do not ask it to stop, say, with an `exit`, or `return`.

Comment: Also, I think comparison of strings using `>` is generally not a good idea. How about `if option in ['1', '2', '3', '4'] ... else`

Comment: Thank you Dan and HonboZhu. I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 2):

One option is the use the exit command:

```
exit()
```

So that the program stops and should be restarted manually.

Another option is to use a while loop like this:

```
while option not in [1,2,3,4]:
     option = input("Please enter the number of your option 1, 2, 3, 4:")
```

This **forces** the user to use a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the input part in a while loop:

```
option = input("Please enter the number of your option 1, 2, 3, 4:")
while option > '4':
  print("Invalid input. Please select 1,2,3 or 4.")  
  option = input("Please enter the number of your option 1, 2, 3, 4:")
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome.

if i'm understanding your question correctly you want it to not execute these lines:

```
num1 = float(input( "Please enter the first value: "))
num2 = float(input( "Please enter the second value: "))
```

if option was greater than 4.

The way I would do that in your code is to put those lines into the if/else block for `if choice < 5` (you currently have print statements describing the input options there, which seems odd.)

A few other thoughts:

- you are using `option` and `choice` as variables when i think they should be the same
- you are making sure the input is a float (`float(input(...))`) but then comparing that to a string (`if choice == '1'`)
- you could have some difficult edge cases, like someone entering 4.5, or -3 as a choice input
- as others have mentioned, you aren't re-asking if the input is invalid, which is a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified to code in below ways to get the desired output,

- removed the choice variable and replaced it with option
- moved the getting extra variables num1 and num2 inside the if block
- replaced the two if's with one if else statement

here is the updated code for reference.

```
#Simple calculator
# define my simple functions

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def min(x, y):
    return x - y

def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

def div(x, y):
    return x / y

# provide options for operations
print("Please select an operation.")
print("For addition select 1. ")
print("For subtraction select 2.")
print("For multiplication  select 3.")
print("For division select 4.")

option = input("Please enter the number of your option 1, 2, 3, 4:")
print option

# limit option to 1,2,3,4
if option in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print("Please select an operation.")
    print("For addition select 1. ")
    print("For subtraction select 2.")
    print("For multiplication  select 3.")
    print("For division select 4.")
    num1 = float(input("Please enter the first value: "))
    num2 = float(input("Please enter the second value: "))
    if option == 1:
        print(num1, " + ", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

    elif option == 2:
        print(num1, " - ", num2, "=", min(num1, num2))

    elif option == 3:
        print(num1, " * ", num2, "=", mul(num1, num2))

    elif option == 4:
        print(num1, " / ", num2, "=", div(num1, num2))
else:
    print("Invalid input. Please select 1,2,3 or 4.")
```

Comment: Much obliged, I have learned so much from your comments and help. Thank you all.

Comment: you could implement switch case, add validation for num1 and num2 etc. https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html